# How do I effectively use crypt()

Tags: php, encryption

I don't understand the documentation at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php).  It appears they are using the encrypted version of password as the salt when testing against the original encryption.

When I insert crypt with out the optional second parameter (the salt) I get different encrypted versions of the same password.  Is this expected behavior?

However if I insert a second parameter of 'd4' then I get the same encrypted passwords for the same password input.  Expected behavior.

Prior to insertion on signup:

```
$pass = crypt('$pass', 'd4'); // after this I insert $pass into the mysql table
```

Testing on signin:

```
$pass = crypt($pass, 'd4'); // after this I test $pass against the mysql table
```

PHP.net documentation:

```
<?php
$password = crypt('mypassword'); // let the salt be automatically generated

/* You should pass the entire results of crypt() as the salt for comparing a
   password, to avoid problems when different hashing algorithms are used. (As
   it says above, standard DES-based password hashing uses a 2-character salt,
   but MD5-based hashing uses 12.) */
if (crypt($user_input, $password) == $password) {
   echo "Password verified!";
}
?>
```

How does this work?

Comment: "it appears they are using the encrypted version of password as the salt" where do you see that?

Comment: The code is posted above - Why are they salting the user input with the password when the original password encrption had no salt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `crypt()` only uses the first two characters (or whatever `CRYPT_SALT_LENGTH` is) of the salt argument, passing in the encrypted password (of which the first characters are the salt originally used to encrypt it) does the right thing.

If no salt argument is passed in, a random salt is generated and used.

Comment: Wouldn't a random salt make the encrypted password unrecoverable?

Comment: `crypt` is one-way.  When you get a password to test, you `crypt` it with the original salt and compare the encrypted values.  By design, you have no way to recover the password after running it through `crypt` short of brute-force guessing until you find it.

Comment: In the php.net example the stored password use not salt, when they test against the password they use user_input as the salt, perhaps this is an error in their documentation, I have seen this before.

Comment: When you first save the password, you should use a random salt.  When you're checking whether what was sent as the password is the same as what was originally sent, then you pass (the first two characters of) the encrypted password - actually the salt - to the `crypt()` function as the salt, and it will return the same value for the encrypted password if the password given is the same as originally given, or a different answer (starting with the same two salt characters) if the new putative password is different from the original.

Comment: What is confusing it that even though the salt parameter is left out, salt is still being automatically generated (not randomly in this case) and inserted as the first two letters of the encrypted password... so that it is self descriptive, i.e. the encrypted password contains data explaining how it was encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is... Is it normal that with certain encryption ciphers you are returned with different encrypted strings for the same password/input? The answer is yes. Not to sure what you are refering to about salt. Salt it just salt. In the end it is a deturant and means nothing. Using passwords or encrypted forms of passwords as salt is not recommended, but using some random hash (base64) of a phrase is commonly used. Let me know if this doesn't any, and I'll try again.

Comment: O.K. I thought I would simply add two crypt() statements to my code, one for inserting the password and one for testing it.  Added above.

Comment: Are you wanting a safe way to store users passwords in a database, in a one-way encrypted form that can later be validated on the next login?

Comment: According to Headfirst Mysql/PHP this is the way to go.

Comment: Try something like taking the md5 or sha1 of the password, and injecting salt in various places.